# Ionic Tabs in iOS displays part of the icon at the bottom of tab

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing a mobile app in ionic that uses tabs. 
When I transfer from one tab to the other(click the other tab) a portion of the icon is being displayed at the bottom of the tab for less than a second. It's like a flicker that disappear after a second.

It only happens on iOS. Before I was also using the same project and it doesn't happen. I'm not sure what was the cause since I did a lot(I was trying to fix the bugs in iOS9)... I updated my ionic, cordova and downloaded the latest xcode(I have 2 xcode in my workspace, I'm testing it in 6.3 and 7.0). I'm using an iPhone with iOS 8.1.

Pleases see the image below:

[image: Ionic Tab in iOS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a similar issue with my tabs on iOS9. By looking at the console while running on the iOS simulator, I saw some $digest loop error.

This is a bug specific to iOS 9 caused by ngRoute. Applying the patch provided by Ionic did the trick.

Here is the related issue: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4082

And here is the patch: https://gist.github.com/IgorMinar/863acd413e3925bf282c

Comment: Hi Mitch, thanks for the answer, I was using iOS 8.1 and it still happens... I think it was on the angular/ionic libraries that I'm using. It doesn't coincide with each other?.. Luckily I still have my old project and the libraries were not updated yet so I just copied the libraries from my old project and override the libraries in the new project.